# Is there a correlation between self-employment and wealth?

Tags: self-employment

What is the reason that most of America's millionaires are self employed (The fact is as per 'The Millionaire Next door'?) Point to note is that the reverse is not true as per the book

Comment: If the fact you cite is true, then yes there is clearly a correlation. The important question is if theres a causal relationship.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In a well-managed company, employees bring more dollars to their employers than the employers pay the employees (salary and benefits).  Employees trade potential reward for security (a regular paycheck).  Employers take on the risk of needing to meet payroll and profit from the company's income, minus expenses.

The potential rewards are much higher as an employer (self or otherwise), so the ones that do make it do quite well.  But this is also consistent with your other statement that the reverse is not true; the risk of self-employment is high, and many self-employed people don't become millionaires.

Answer (score 3):

If you could find a breakdown, I suspect that it would show not just that they are *self employed* but own their own company.

There are many people that are self employed, many of them make a good living at it, but are not millionaires.  My neighbour the plumber is a perfect example of this sort of self-employed and comfortable but not rich person.

The key to wealth growth is to own (a significant part of) a company.  It one way to leverage a smaller amount of money to something much larger.  Plough your profits back in to the company to grow it, pay yourself reasonably for some time as the company grows.  After it is some size, you can afford to pay yourself more of the profits, if not sell it as a going concern to someone else.

One last thought - I am assuming that your book is claiming that they made their money through self-employment, instead of choosing to become self employed  after striking rich somewhere.  If I were to win the lottery, I might then become a *self-employed* something, but in that case it was not my self-employment that got me there.

Comment: Please clarify: `instead of choosing after striking rich somewhere.`

Comment: Chasing, I presume.

Answer (score 2):

The key to becoming wealthy as a self-employed person is the *drive* to be successful. A driven person, who starts their own company (or companies, should they fail), will find success. Assuming that you define success as the accumulation of wealth, then yes, self-employment is **correlated** with wealth.

But as matt mentions in the comments, there is no *casual* (in the statistical sense) relationship between self-employment and wealth. While I can't say for sure, I would argue that drive is more important that the employment situation.

Answer (score -1):

Many studies show that the wealthiest households are self employed and small business owners.

But there is significant risk associated, and so the wealth cannot really be enjoyed.

Comment: While true, this is just restating what's stated in the question.